# How come the image is not displayed?

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

I'm learning php and mysqli.  I wrote a program that allows users to upload name and image to a database.  They can click on a name in the database and clicking on a name, they'll see a picture of that person.

Below are my PHP file.  Everything works except that the image doesn't display.  When I click on a name, all I see is a blue box with a question mark.  Can someone take a look at my code and give me some hints on how to solve this?  Thanks!

main.php

```
    <?php

    //Turn on error reporting
    ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
    //Connects to the database
    $mysqli = new mysqli("abc", "abc","abc", "abc");
    if($mysqli->connect_errno){
        echo "Connection error: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
    }
?>  


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.js"></script>
        <script>$(document).ready(function() {$("form").validate();});</script>
        <title>Homework</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <p></p>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>Homework</div>
        <p></p>
        <div>
            <form method="post" action="index.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                Celebrity Name: <input type="text" name="c_name">
                Celebrity Photo: <input type="file" name="c_picture">
                <input type="submit" name="add" value="Upload">
            </form>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div>
        <table>
        <tr>
            <td>See below for a list of celebrities in our database</td>
        </tr>
        <?php
            //Display names in the celebrity database
            if(!($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT c_id, c_name FROM celebrity"))){
                echo "Prepare failed: "  . $stmt->errno . " " . $stmt->error;
            }

            if(!$stmt->execute()){
                echo "Execute failed: "  . $mysqli->connect_errno . " " . $mysqli->connect_error;
            }

            if(!$stmt->bind_result($c_id, $c_name)){
                echo "Bind failed: "  . $mysqli->connect_errno . " " . $mysqli->connect_error;
            }

            while($stmt->fetch()){
                echo "<tr><td><a href='img.php?c_id=".$c_id."'>" . $c_name . "</a></td></tr>";
                //echo "<tr>\n<td>\n" . $c_name . "\n</td>\n</tr>";

            }

            $stmt->close();
        ?>
        </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

img.php

```
    <?php

    //Turn on error reporting
    ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
    //Connects to the database
    $mysqli = new mysqli("blah", "blah","blah", "blah");
    if($mysqli->connect_errno){
        echo "Connection error: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
    }

    $c_id=1;
    //retrieve the blob
    if(!($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT c_picture FROM celebrity where c_name = ?"))){
        echo "Prepare failed: "  . $stmt->errno . " " . $stmt->error;
    }

    //if(!($stmt->bind_param("i",$_GET['c_id']))){
    if(!($stmt->bind_param("i",$c_id))){
        echo "Bind failed: "  . $stmt->errno . " " . $stmt->error;
    }

    if(!$stmt->execute()){
        echo "Execute failed: "  . $mysqli->connect_errno . " " . $mysqli->connect_error;
    }

    $stmt->store_result();

    if(!$stmt->bind_result($c_picture)){
        echo "Bind failed: "  . $mysqli->connect_errno . " " . $mysqli->connect_error;
    }

    $stmt->fetch();
    header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
    echo $c_picture;

    $stmt->close();
?>
```

index.php

```
    <?php

    //Turn on error reporting
    ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
    //Connects to the database
    $mysqli = new mysqli("blah", "blah","blah", "blah");
    if($mysqli->connect_errno){
        echo "Connection error: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
    }

    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
    {
        $errorinfo = $_FILES['c_picture']['error'];
        $img = $_FILES['c_picture']['name'];
        $imgTmp = $_FILES['c_picture']['tmp_name'];
        $imgSize = $_FILES['c_picture']['size'];
        $imgType = $_FILES['c_picture']['type'];
    }

    //Check image type and size
    if (($imgType == 'image/jpeg' || $imgType == 'image/gif' || $imgType == 'image/png') && $imgSize < 1048576)
    {
        //Insert name and image file into celebrity database (c_name, c_picture) values (?, ?)
        if(!($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO celebrity(c_name, c_picture) VALUES (?, ?)")))
        {
            echo "Prepare failed: "  . $stmt->errno . " " . $stmt->error;
        }


        if(!($stmt->bind_param("sb",$_POST['c_name'], $img)))
        {
            echo "Bind failed: "  . $stmt->errno . " " . $stmt->error;
        }


        if(!$stmt->execute())
        {
            echo "Execute failed: "  . $stmt->errno . " " . $stmt->error;
        }   
        else 
        {
            echo "Added " . $stmt->affected_rows . " celebrity to database.";
        }

    }
    else
    {
        echo "Only jpegs, gifs, and pngs under 1MB can be uploaded";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not saving the image data when inserting, if you print:

```
$img = $_FILES['c_picture']['name'];
echo $img;
```

It is only the image's original name, instead you need to save the file data. If you wanted to just output the image directly:

```
header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
echo file_get_contents($_FILES['c_picture']['tmp_name']);
```

What you need to do is take the image data from `$_FILES['c_picture']['tmp_name']` and store it as BLOB or LONGBLOB in your database. I see you are already using BLOB, so you only need to change:

```
$img = $_FILES['c_picture']['name'];
```

instead, use:

```
$img = file_get_contents($_FILES['c_picture']['tmp_name']);
```

Also, your header should output the right image type, maybe you can save it to the database too.

In a real world application you shouldn't store the image's binary in a database, a better approach would be to store the image in a folder and just save the address in the database.

Answer (score 0):

The link to the page that displays picture in your main.php is `img.php`:

```
<a href='img.php?c_id=".$c_id."'>
```

Yet the Name of the file you posted here that display picture is viewfile.php, so just change your link to point to viewfile.php:

```
<a href='viewfile.php?c_id=".$c_id."'>
```

Comment: Sorry. I will edit my post. It should be "img.php".  It still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

just check something, if you entered the full image tag in the db then there is a problem, but if you just entered the name of the image to the db, to view it, you should do something like this

```
<img src="images/$c_name" alt="$c_name">
```

instead of just $c_name.